# imshow(img, cmap=cm.gray) shows a white for 128 value

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm moving from MatLab to python and playing around with the imshow function.

I can't seem to get my head around why it doesn't show the value 128 as grey with I have chosen the cmap to be gray-scale.

[image: Code example]

It seems as it uses the grayscale for highest (128) and lowest values.. I want it to use the grayscale for [0:255]. How do I do that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the `vmin` and `vmax` parameters:

```
plt.imshow(bg, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'), vmin=0, vmax=255)
```

Without specifying `vmin` and `vmax`, `plt.imshow` auto-adjusts its range to the min and max of the data.

---

I do not know of a way to set default `vmin` and `vmax` parameters for all imshow plots, but you could use `functools.partial` to prepare a custom imshow-like command with default parameters set:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import functools

bwimshow = functools.partial(plt.imshow, vmin=0, vmax=255,
                             cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))

dots = np.random.randn(10, 10)*255
bwimshow(dots)
cbar = plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :-) - are there any way to set as default values for all plots?

Comment: Yes, using `functools.partial`. See above.